# How to load app configuration from appsettings.json in MAUI startup?

Tags: configuration, startup, maui

I would need to retrieve my app settings from an appsettings.json file in a MAUI application.
I tagged it a MauiAsset generation action, and I can see it in the assets directory of of the generated apk.
It doesn't seem to be available in ConfigureAppConfiguration and no AddJsonFile extension exists to add it in the application builder.

- Should I use another generation action?
- What is the good way to retrieve it?

  ```
    public void Configure(IAppHostBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((app, config) =>
            {
                // I should be able to work with appsettings here
            })
            .ConfigureServices(svcs =>
            {

            })
            .UseMauiApp<App>();
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ConfigureAppConfiguration` was just added with [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/2137) a couple of days ago. It will probably show up for the next release.

If you really need it now you could add it as an embedded resource and do the deserialization from JSON yourself. If you could wait a bit longer you probably want to do that.

Comment: It shouldn't be an embedded resource since the app itself or a user may edit the appsettings.json file. I still can't see `ConfigureAppConfiguration` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the usual host builder by using the `MauiAppBuilder.Host` getter.

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
    })
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .Host
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((app, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    })
    .ConfigureServices((ctx, svcs) =>
    {

    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddSerilog();
    });
```

To get app location and appsetings path, use the following:

```
Assembly CallingAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Version VersionRuntime = CallingAssembly.GetName().Version;
string AssemblyLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(CallingAssembly.Location);
string ConfigFile = Path.Combine(AssemblyLocation, "appsettings.json");
```

Comment: .Host does not seem to exist when I try it (.Net 6).

Comment: @John indeed, it's no longer available